# Scala parse/split a string

Tags: scala

There is a string represented as follows:

```
val str = "teacher.name:ABC DEF student.age:20 teacher.gender:male teacher.tag:123 student.name:XYZ"
```

I want to group by the teacher and student, so the result will be:

```
val teacher = "name:ABC DEF gender:male tag:123"

val student = "age:20 name:XYZ"
```

In this example, either "teacher." or "student." is kind of meaningful delimiter. Assume there is no "." in other places.

How can I write the code using Scala to do it nicely?

Comment: Hmm, OK so what is the meaningful delimiter here? What if you had names like "Howard Studently" or "Janet Suteacher"?  What's the marker that is guaranteed to identify the beginning/end of each record?

Comment: In this example, either "teacher." or "student." is kind of meaningful delimiter. Assume there is no "." in other places. Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do it.

```
val str = "teacher.name:ABC DEF student.age:20 teacher.gender:male teacher.tag:123 student.name:XYZ"

val teacher = str.split("teacher.").map(_.split("student.").head.trim).tail.mkString(", ")
// teacher: String = name:ABC DEF, gender:male, tag:123

val student = str.split("student.").map(_.split("teacher.").head.trim).tail.mkString(", ")
// student: String = age:20, name:XYZ
```

A bit on the verbose side, but a straight forward algorithm: split on the label you want, sub-split on the label you don't.

Comment: Looks like if the name contains '-', it will not work.

Comment: I don't know why you say that. Have your tried it? According to my tests having a '-' in the name, or elsewhere, doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

"Nicely" is relative, and it's probably just best to walk the string, but a brute-force answer leaning on scala's collection methods might:

```
// tokenize the input
val tokens = str.reverse.split(':').flatMap(_.split(" ", 2)).map(_.reverse).reverse

// zip tokens into key-value pairs
val pairs = (tokens zip tokens.drop(1)).zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0).map(_._1)

// group key-value pairs and join string
pairs.groupBy(_._1.split('.').head).mapValues(_.collect({ case (a, b) => a.split('.').last + ":" + b }).mkString(" "))

// Map(student -> age:20 name:XYZ, teacher -> name:ABC DEF gender:male tag:123)
```

```